# Sharing Variables between functions of a PHP Class

Tags: php

I have code that follows this structure:

```
class someClass
{
    private static $pay = 0;

    //something like this...
    public static function run()
    {
        if ($_SESSION['title']== "whatever" and $_SESSION['rank'] == "1")
        {
            self::$pay = 50000;
        }
    }

    public static function benefits()
    {
        self::$pay = 50000 * 1.30;
        benefits = self:$pay;
        echo benefits;
    }
}
```

Then I try calling benefits like this...

```
someClass::benefits();
```

But it's always set to zero. It never changes when the condition from the if statement is met.

Is there something I am doing here that is obviously wrong? I am not getting any errors.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure about this line: `benefits = self:$pay;` ?

Comment: That should give a fatal error though, no way that cannot produce any error if it is not a typo.

Comment: It would be best if you provide us with the real code and not something that is a little bit similar but full of other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
<?php
class someClass
{
    private static $pay = 0;

    //something like this...
    public static function run()
    {
        if ($_SESSION['title']== "whatever" and $_SESSION['rank'] == "1")
        {
            self::$pay = 50000;
        }
    }

    public static function benefits()
    {
        self::$pay = 50000 * 1.30;
        $benefits = self::$pay;
        return $benefits;
    }
}

echo someClass::benefits();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think you want to `echo` values from that class function.  I highly recommend `return`ing then.  And then if you echo them immediately, fine, but you shouldn't echo like that from functions.  Without seeing how this is used, that would be my first guess.

Answer (score 1):

inside the benefits function, benefits should be $benefits if you intend to use it as a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `benefits` as if it was constant (which assignment to is not allowed in php)--you probably mean `$benefits`. Change your code to this:

```
    self::$pay = 50000 * 1.30;
    $benefits = self::$pay;
    echo $benefits;
```

Comment: `$benefits = self::$pay;` with 2 colons!

Comment: @NullUserException I know it is, but it is still wrong. If this answer should be seen as correct those errors should removed. Also it does not matter if `run` was excuted before since in the very first line he overwrites `$pay` with a constant expression.

Comment: @clentfort True. I don't think the OP knows exactly what they're doing, because a lot of the code doesn't make sense. S/he says *"it never changes when the condition from the if statement is met."* which implies the `if` should be a relevant factor in the calculation. I don't know how to make sense of the code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function benefits()
{
    self::$pay = 50000 * 1.30;
    echo self::$pay;
}
```

should be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
 benefits = self:$pay;
```

To

```
 benefits = self::$pay;
```